# How to make the same button run different code everytime it is clicked?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am currently doing a school project, I am making a Credit Card machine. I need the 'Enter Button' to
 run different code when it is clicked. The first click must get the card number from an edit ps... (I clear the edit once the card number has been retrieved), and the second click must get the pin from the same edit.
How would I do this?

```
procedure TfrmMainMenu.btbtnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);

var

 sCvv,sPin:string;

begin

iCount2:=0;

sCardNumber:=lbledtCardInfo.Text;

if (Length(sCardNumber)<>16) AND (iCount2=0) then

 begin

    ShowMessage('Card number has to 16 digits,please try again!!');

  end

  else

  begin

  Inc(iCount2);

  lbledtCardInfo.clear;

  lbledtCardInfo.EditLabel.Caption:='Enter Pin' ;

  btbtnEnter.Enabled:=false;

  end; //if

  if iCount2=2 then

  begin

     btbtnEnter.Enabled:=true;

    sPin:=lbledtCardInfo.Text;

     ShowMessage(sPin);//returns a blank

  end;
```

Comment: I see that you ask many questions, which is great! But as I think I have said before, we do prefer if you include your own attempt in the Q. Indeed, if you don't attempt to solve the problem yourself first, you won't learn much from the school project. Also, I strongly recommend buying a good book about Delphi programming, or at the very least find some comprehensive and high-quality online material. That's probably the best way to really learn it.

Comment: Notice that you test `iCount2 = 0` immediately after setting `iCount2 := 0`. Thus, that test will always be `True`. Furthermore, the later test `iCount2 = 2` will always be `False` because the value starts at `0` and you only have one `Inc` in between.

Comment: Thank you but it still does not work. God Bless

Comment: Use `if iCount2=1 then` instead of `if iCount2=2 then`, because 'Inc(0) = 1`

Comment: @Val: Except `Inc` is a procedure, not a function. But we do get the point. (However, `Succ(0) = 1`.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't see where I said what Inc is, but thank you for explaining. As you can see, I did not mark Inc (0) = 0 as code, but just show what would happen if the parameter is 0.By the way, what is Succ and does it come from success?

Comment: @ValMarinov: `Succ` is the successor function. It returns the next value in the sequence. It works for all ordinal types, so, e.g., `Succ(4) = 5`, `Succ(-95) = -94`, and given `type TCar = (cVolvo, cPeugeot, cRenault)`, `Succ(cVolvo) = cPeugeot`. Similarly, `Pred` is the predecessor function, so `Pred(123) = 122`, `Pred(-100) = -101`, and `Pred(cPeugeot) = cVolvo`. So while `Inc(0)` doesn't evaluate to `1`, `Succ(0)` does. (`Inc` is a procedure with a `var` parameter; `Succ` is a function. Other than that, they do the same thing for integers.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Really? Great. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do everything in a single event handler. There are several different ways to handle that. However, a different solution would be to use separate event handlers for each task, and then each task can assign a new handler for the next click to perform, eg:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMainMenu.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // you can set this at design-time if desired...
  btbtnEnter.OnClick := GetCCNumber;
end;

procedure TfrmMainMenu.GetCCNumber(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sCardNumber := lbledtCardInfo.Text;
  if Length(sCardNumber) <> 16 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Card number has to 16 digits,please try again!!');
    Exit;
  end;
  lbledtCardInfo.Clear;
  lbledtCardInfo.EditLabel.Caption := 'Enter Pin' ;
  btbtnEnter.OnClick := GetCCPin;
end;

procedure TfrmMainMenu.GetCCPin(Sender: TObject);
var
  sPin: string;
begin
  sPin := lbledtCardInfo.Text;
  if Length(sPin) <> 4 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Card Pin has to 4 digits,please try again!!');
    Exit;
  end;
  ShowMessage(sPin);
  ...
  lbledtCardInfo.Clear;
  lbledtCardInfo.EditLabel.Caption := 'Enter Number' ;
  btbtnEnter.OnClick := GetCCNumber;
end;
```

A variation of this would be to create multiple buttons that overlap each other in the UI, and then you can toggle their `Visible` property back and forth as needed, eg:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMainMenu.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // you can set this at design-time if desired...
  btbtnCCPinEnter.Visible := False;
  btbtnCCNumEnter.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TfrmMainMenu.btbtnCCNumEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sCardNumber := lbledtCardInfo.Text;
  if Length(sCardNumber) <> 16 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Card number has to 16 digits,please try again!!');
    Exit;
  end;
  lbledtCardInfo.Clear;
  lbledtCardInfo.EditLabel.Caption := 'Enter Pin' ;
  btbtnCCNumEnter.Visible := False;
  btbtnCCPinEnter.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TfrmMainMenu.btbtnCCPinEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sPin: string;
begin
  sPin := lbledtCardInfo.Text;
  if Length(sPin) <> 4 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Card Pin has to 4 digits,please try again!!');
    Exit;
  end;
  ShowMessage(sPin);
  ...
  lbledtCardInfo.Clear;
  lbledtCardInfo.EditLabel.Caption := 'Enter Number' ;
  btbtnCCPinEnter.Visible := False;
  btbtnCCNumEnter.Visible := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you test `iCount2 = 0` immediately after setting `iCount2 := 0`. Thus, that test will always be `True`. Furthermore, the later test `iCount2 = 2` will always be `False` because the value starts at 0 and you only have one `Inc` in between.

Instead try the following.

Add two string fields `FCardNumber` and `FPin` to your form class:

```
private
  FCardNumber: string;
  FPin: string;
```

Also create an enumerated type `TEntryStage = (esCardNumber, esPin)` and add a field of this type. This will make your code look like this:

```
private
type
  TEntryStage = (esCardNumber, esPin);
var
  FCardNumber: string;
  FPin: string;
  FEntryStage: TEntryStage;
```

In Delphi, class fields (class member variables) are always initialized, so `FEntryStage` will be `esCardNumber` (=`TEntryStage(0)`) when the form is newly created.

Add a `TLabeledEdit` (I see you use those) and a `TButton`; name them `eInput` and `btnNext`, respectively. Let the labeled edit's caption be `Card number:` and the caption of the button be `Next`.

Now add the following `OnClick` handler to the button:

```
procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  case FEntryStage of
    esCardNumber:
      begin

        // Save card number
        FCardNumber := eInput.Text;

        // Prepare for the next stage
        eInput.Clear;
        eInput.EditLabel.Caption := 'Pin:';

        FEntryStage := esPin;

      end;

    esPin:
      begin

        // Save pin
        FPin := eInput.Text;

        // Just do something with the data
        ShowMessageFmt('Card number: %s'#13#10'Pin: %s', [FCardNumber, FPin]);

      end;
  end;

end;
```

You might notice that you cannot trigger the `Next` button using `Enter`, which is very annoying. To fix this, do

```
procedure TForm1.eInputEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnNext.Default := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.eInputExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnNext.Default := False;
end;
```

Much better!

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful

Comment: @Fuzail: Just make sure you understand it properly!